# Dart ~ Set Repository once for all dependenceis in pubspec.yaml

Tags: dart, dart-pub, pubspec

I have a Dart project with a list of dependencies. I want that all those dependencies are resolved from the company's Artifactory repository. Is there a way how I can just enter the repository's address once in the pubspec.yaml and have that repository be used as the default repository for all dependencies? I specifically do *not* want to have to specify it for each of the dependencies.

Coming from Java/Gradle, I am used to something like this being part of all our files:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.company.int:12345/artifactory/Public/'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Dart as well? Or is that something that is not possible in Dart?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible. Each dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` have to have a specific path/git reference.

You could however use a yaml anchor to store a variable to e.g. a common git repository, and then use that with specific paths for each dependency.

### pubspec.yaml:

```
git_url_specification: &mainGitUrl https://github.com/specific_account/some_repository.git

dependencies:
  package_1:
    git:
      url: *mainGitUrl
      path: package_1/path/in/repo
      ref: main
  package_2:
    git:
      url: *mainGitUrl
      path: package_2/path/in/repo
      ref: develop
```